# Node INTL locale Collation

Tags: node.js, sorting, internationalization, collation, icu

I'm working on a side project that involves sorting Japanese and Thai strings.  When I was testing the sorting in client-side Javascript, I was able to use `a.localeCompare(b, "languageCode")` which worked.  When I tried this same logic in Node, it did not work, because the [Node INTL object](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Intl) is restricted to English as the default.

I want to customize my node build as described in the above link, and came across the [ICU4C-data Node Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icu4c-data), which I understand contains a full set of ICU data. I've been playing around with different build flags, like the one specified by the (sparse) README: `--icu-data-dir=node_modules/icu4c-data`, to no avail - no matter which flags I set I cannot get the [INTL Collator's compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare) to give the expected results.  Is there an obvious flag that I'm missing, or key assumption I have wrong?

Here are a few things important notes/resources:

- The end goal is Thai & Japanese collation - if there's another approach using Node to implement this, I'm open to suggestions.
- Collation must be done in Node
- I'm going to be relying on [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - mainly looking for a comparator
- Using Node 0.12, with [ECMA support](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.1.1)
- My first time customizing a Node build (~1 month experience)

Answer (score 1):

Install the [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) package instead. It will give instructions on how to load the rest of the data.

Also note that future node versions should not require any configuration to pick up the new data, you can see [#3460](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3460) if interested.

I need to fix the `icu4c-data`'s readme to reflect this.